# Which program was used to make this annotations on the pic?

Tags: fonts

This might be a stupid question, I know the same result can be achieved with Photoshop or any basic photo editing software, but it seems to me like some kind of OS X software that has this cool arrows and fonts styles that lets you add annotations on pictures with ease. Anyone knows it? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preview does this click the toolbox icon top right

Comment: Preview doesn't has this kind of arrow or font effect, or at least I wasn't able to find it...

Comment: its https://evernote.com/products/skitch but I thought you wanted a mac app